# Simple Implementation of Video Capture by using Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, video, frame

I would like to display the video frame in thread. But when I run the below code, I feel that the program executes but does not display the live video frame. I felt there might be an error in processing this Waitkey(but not sure)`if(waitKey(30) >= 0)`. Can anyone suggest me what I need to do in order to display the video frame in thread.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <pthread.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


void *WebCam(void *arg){

    VideoCapture cap(0);
    for (; ; ) {
        Mat frame;
        cap >> frame;
        imshow("frame", frame);
        if(waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(){
    pthread_t thread1;
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, &WebCam, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I get an Error like shown below :

```
2017-02-24 11:22:00.091003 moment[3249:460947] [General] An uncaught exception was raised

2017-02-24 11:22:00.091050 moment[3249:460947] [General] nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!
2017-02-24 11:22:00.091127 moment[3249:460947] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc1430e7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffd601acad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fffbf6533fd -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 4471
    3   libopencv_highgui.3.2.dylib         0x0000000100ce86b8 cvWaitKey + 408
    4   libopencv_highgui.3.2.dylib         0x0000000100ce538b _ZN2cv7waitKeyEi + 11
    5   moment                              0x0000000100000b54 _Z6WebCamPv + 180
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563c50 _pthread_body + 180
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563b9c _pthread_body + 0
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563385 thread_start + 13
)
2017-02-24 11:22:00.091219 moment[3249:460947] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'nextEventMatchingMask should only be called from the Main Thread!'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fffc1430e7b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fffd601acad objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   AppKit                              0x00007fffbf6533fd -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 4471
    3   libopencv_highgui.3.2.dylib         0x0000000100ce86b8 cvWaitKey + 408
    4   libopencv_highgui.3.2.dylib         0x0000000100ce538b _ZN2cv7waitKeyEi + 11
    5   moment                              0x0000000100000b54 _Z6WebCamPv + 180
    6   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563c50 _pthread_body + 180
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563b9c _pthread_body + 0
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000102563385 thread_start + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Check the value returned by waitKey: `uchar key = waitKey(30); if(key >= 0 ) {break;}` Which value is `key`?

Comment: @Miki When I try to print `int c = waitKey(30);
        cout<<"c ="<<c;
        if(c >= 0)
            break;
` it does not print. But I have updated the error